# Can't seem to get PHP form to display

Tags: php, post

I am working on my version 2 of my portfolio site, I had a working mailer I created with a guide about a year ago, transferred it, and can't get my page to display now.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
    //if "email" is filled out, send email
       {
                //send email
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
            $subject = $_REQUEST["My_Portfolio_Website"] ;
            $message = $_REQUEST['message'] . "\nName: " . $name . "\nEmail: ".$email; "\n \nMessage: ".$message;

            echo "<h1>Thank you for contacting me. I will get back to you ASAP!</h1>";

        }else{
        //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
            echo <form method="post" action="contact.php" class="connect">
          <div>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" required>
            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
            <label for="message">Your Message</label>
          </div>
          <div class="metro">
            <div class="metro-button" type="submit">Click me</div> 
            </div>
        </form>

        } 
?>
```

I ran it through a PHP syntax checker and it did not pull anything out, does anyone have any ideas?

For reference: Here is the original code I used on Version 1. I formatted it so it would display the email a little more cleaner, which probably royally screwed it up.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
    //if "email" is filled out, send email
       {
                //send email
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
            $subject = $_REQUEST["My Portfolio Website"] ;
            $message = $_REQUEST['message'].", Name: ".$name.", ".$phone.", Email: ".$email;
            mail("TylerJStelmach@gmail.com", $subject, $message, "From:" . $email);
            echo "<h1>Thank you for contacting me. I will get back to you ASAP!</h1>";
        }else{
        //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
            echo "<form method='post' action='index.php'>

                <input type='text' input name='name' id='name' class='contacttext' placeholder=' Your Name' required>
                <input type='text' input name='email' id='email' class='contacttext' placeholder=' Your Email Address' required>
                <textarea input type='text' name='message' id='message' class='contacttext' placeholder=' Your Message' cols='55' rows='5' required></textarea>

                <input type='submit' id='submit' class='submitcontacttext' value='Send Message'>
                </form>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Lol .... inside ` if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))` statement, where is the line of code which sends email?

Comment: There's no way that passed a syntax checker. You're missing quotes around the argument to `echo` in the `else` block, and it doesn't have `;` at the end.

Comment: Its better first you turn on Error Reporting in that file and correct those error

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors.

Also, your snipplet does not contain code to send mail.

Corrected code is as following:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
     {
                        //send email
                $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
                $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
                $subject = $_REQUEST["My_Portfolio_Website"] ;
                $message = $_REQUEST['message'] . "\nName: " . $name . "\nEmail: ".$email; "\n \nMessage: ".$message;

                echo "<h1>Thank you for contacting me. I will get back to you ASAP!</h1>";

        }else{
        //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
                echo '<form method="post" action="contact.php" class="connect">
            <div>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
                <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" required>
                <label for="email">Your Email</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
                <label for="message">Your Message</label>
            </div>
            <div class="metro">
                <div class="metro-button" type="submit">Click me</div> 
                </div>
        </form>';
        } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

as all are saying where is the line to send mail but as i have seen your site there is no sign of any code.

as i am just guessing, even if the `if` is false, the `else` should run as it is running in my localhost.

the problem must be something with your sever.
put a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top it will show errors if it there.

else try writing in a new file.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
    //if "email" is filled out, send email
       {
                //send email
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
            $subject = $_REQUEST["My_Portfolio_Website"] ;
            $message = $_REQUEST['message'] . "\nName: " . $name . "\nEmail: ".$email; "\n \nMessage: ".$message;

            echo "<h1>Thank you for contacting me. I will get back to you ASAP!</h1>";

        }else{
            ?>

            <form method="post" action="contact.php" class="connect">
          <div>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" required>
            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
            <label for="message">Your Message</label>
          </div>
          <div class="metro">
            <div class="metro-button" type="submit">Click me</div> 
            </div>
        </form>
<?php
        } 
?>
```

Comment: I actually just took the page off line for now, I'm going to rebuild the page and file structure.

Comment: hey i got it you have to enclose the echo in " " these... or just close the php tag and then open it.. will sow you how..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by re-writing the original code I had based on the guide I used about a year ago, I came up with this for the answer which indeed works.

For all of the handling of where the information goes and how it was formated I included this chunk of `php` before I declared the doctype.

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="myemail@email.com";
    $subject="Client Mail";
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $message=$_POST["message"];


    $mailBody="Name: $name\nEmail: $email\n\nMessage: $message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$email>");

    $thankYou="<p class='thank-you'>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

From here, I figured out that the reason it wasn't submitting to it's own page was because my submit button was neither a `button` or `input`. I had it set as a `div` so with some tweaks here and there I rewrote the lower half to include an `input` as the submit. Which left me with this:

```
<?=$thankYou ?>
```

I included a small amount of text to display ( the `$thankYou` ) when you submit to the page and it reloads.

```
 <form method="post" action="contact.php" class="connect">
          <div>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" required>
            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
            <label for="message">Your Message</label>
          </div>
          <div class="metro">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="metro-button submit-me">
            </div>
        </form>
```

So now when submitted, the email comes in with:
The 'from' being set by `$email`
The 'subject' being set by `$subject`
and the message (`$message`) being formatted in this manner:

```
Name: John Doe
Email: JDoe@fake.com

Message: This is John Doe's message.
```

My apologies for the terrible question phrasing before hand, it was late at night and I was getting frustrated and losing my place, got a good nights rest and was able to solve it.

Here is the **[live version](http://idesignradthings.com/html/main-pages/contact.php)**, I encourage you to test it, it works for me perfectly, hopefully this snippet can help someone else in the future!